# How to plot multiple graphs with a multi index data frame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataset with a multi-index and I would like to graph based on one index and one of the columns. 
I tried referencing the data, '% Smokers', based on the index. The two indexes are Age Group and Year.

I want the graph to have 4 lines, for each age group, with Year as the x-axis.

The tail of my  dataset looks like:

```
                       % Smokers    Cigs per Day    Smoker Count    Total Count
   Age Group    Year                


          4.0   2003    9.221673    14.947439   86486.103843    9.378570e+05
          1.0   2002    23.668647   7.832528    185319.850343   7.829761e+05
          2.0   2002    24.130250   10.379573   616136.073633   2.553376e+06
          3.0   2002    23.300126   13.569244   389576.705723   1.671994e+06
          4.0   2002    9.892616    12.739635   89247.050214    9.021583e+05
```

I tried the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize = (20,10))

ax[0].plot(part1_df["% Smokers"].loc[1.0])
ax[0].plot(part1_df["% Smokers"].loc[2.0])
ax[0].plot(part1_df["% Smokers"].loc[3.0])
ax[0].plot(part1_df["% Smokers"].loc[4.0])
```

I'm getting a KeyError: '% Smokers'

Comment: As reported in [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the post to remove the image of the code.